# Substitute column values in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables and I want to see in the first one the values which come from the others. Let me explain better:

table lesson

```
+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------+-----------+
| LessonCode       | SubjectCode    | ClassCode      | hour       | day       |
+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------+-----------+
| 1                | 10             | 1              | 15         | m         |
| 2                | 11             | 2              | 20         | t         |
| 3                | 12             | 3              | 30         | w         |
+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------+-----------+
```

table class

```
+------------------+----------------+
| ClassCode        | ClassName      |
+------------------+----------------+
| 1                | Class1         |
| 2                | class2         |
| 3                | class3         |
+------------------+----------------+
```

table subject

```
+------------------+----------------+
| subjectCode      | SubjectName    |
+------------------+----------------+
| 10               | Maths          |
| 11               | English        |
| 12               | Greek          |
+------------------+----------------+
```

I'd Like to insert in `lesson` table the columns `SubjectName` and `ClassName`in place of `SubjectCode` and `ClassCode`, having the follower table:

```
+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------+-----------+
| LessonCode       | SubjectName    | ClassName      | hour       | day       |
+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------+-----------+
| 1                | Maths          | Class1         | 15         | m         |
| 2                | English        | Class2         | 20         | t         |
| 3                | Greek          | Class3         | 30         | w         |
+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------+-----------+
```

How can I do?

Comment: Are you saying you want to denormalize the table, or you just want a query that provides that end result?

Comment: just want a query that provides the end result, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a job for `JOIN`s!  `INNER JOIN` to the rescue!

```
SELECT LessonCode, SubjectName, ClassName, hour, day
FROM lesson
JOIN class on lesson.ClassCode = class.ClassCode
JOIN subject on lesson.SubjectCode = subject.SubjectCode
```

Comment: @bluefeet: Thanks!  I was actually just about to make one :-)

Comment: @bluefeet Playing it a little fast and loose with the word "fun" :)